# How can I get the file name of a tf.summary.FileWriter in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

How can I get the file name of a [`tf.summary.FileWriter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170321224015/https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter)) in TensorFlow?

I am aware that I can use  [`get_logdir()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/FileWriter#get_logdir) but  I don't see any similar method to access the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the filename as it's built on the other side of the C++/python interface.

That said, listing the logdir after writing will let you see what is there.